# After an exec, signal SIGCHLD is not SIG_IGN even though it was SIG_IGN before

Tags: python, c++

This is my program `popen_test.cpp`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
    sigset_t sset;
    sigaddset(&sset, SIGCHLD);
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &sset, &sset);
    char command[128] = {0};
    snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "python popen_test.py");
    FILE* file;
    file = popen(command, "r");
    if ( !file )
    {     
        printf("command: %s is error\n", command);
        return -1;
    } 
    char result[256]={0};
    int len = fread(result, sizeof(char), 256, file);
    printf("result is :%s\n", result); 
    int ret = pclose(file);
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        printf("pclose error:%d, errno:%d, str_err:%s\n", ret, errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1; 
    }

}
```

Script is

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGCHLD)
    if test == signal.SIG_DFL:
        print "sig_dfl"
    if test == signal.SIG_IGN:
        print "sig_ign"
    print test
```

POPEN forks a child process; child process calls `exec` to run `python popen_test.py`， I know when `exec` is called, the SIGCHLD signal (when set to SIG_IGN) may or may not be reset to SIG_DFL. Why is the result sig_dfl, not sig_ign?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are not respecting the `restrict` qualifiers on the arguments to [`sigprocmask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigprocmask.html). Your compiler should be complaining about using the same argument twice. You note that [`execv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execv.html)
documents that _If the SIGCHLD signal is set to be ignored by the calling process image, it is unspecified whether the SIGCHLD signal is set to be ignored or to the default action in the new process image._ What are you puzzled about?

Comment: But the 《Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment》 says if the SIGXXX signal is set to be ignored by the calling process image, In the new process the signal is also to be ignored?

Comment: The `execv()` page (referenced in my previous comment) qualifies what APUE says:  _Signals set to the default action (SIG_DFL) in the calling process image shall be set to the default action in the new process image. Except for SIGCHLD, signals set to be ignored (SIG_IGN) by the calling process image shall be set to be ignored by the new process image._  Then comes the bit I quoted originally.  The difference is that APUE is dealing with UNIX; UNIX is not actually POSIX (though the two are very close).  It appears that your platform (what is it?) is why POSIX says what it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not respecting the restrict qualifiers on the arguments to [`sigprocmask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigprocmask.html). Your compiler should be complaining about using the same argument twice.

---

The POSIX specification for [`execv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execv.html) documents:

> Signals set to the default action (SIG_DFL) in the calling process image shall be set to the default action in the new process image. Except for SIGCHLD, signals set to be ignored (SIG_IGN) by the calling process image shall be set to be ignored by the new process image.
>
> If the SIGCHLD signal is set to be ignored by the calling process image, it is unspecified whether the SIGCHLD signal is set to be ignored or to the default action in the new process image.

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2404124/user2404124) comments:

*But the 《Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment》 says if the SIGXXX signal is set to be ignored by the calling process image, In the new process the signal is also to be ignored?*

The difference is that APUE is dealing with UNIX; UNIX is not actually POSIX (though the two are close). POSIX says that a platform can be POSIX-compliant and still reset `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_DFL` even if it was `SIG_IGN` in the original process.  Your code appears to demonstrate that your platform is why POSIX gives the exemption for `SIGCHLD`.

Out of curiosity, which platform are you using?

Comment: linux gun libc 2.4 python 2.4